# How to use GitVersion Environment variables

Tags: f#, environment-variables, f#-fake, appveyor, gitversion

I have a project which I used to build via AppVeyor. The build sequence was the following:

1. Install and run GitVersion
2. Build project
3. Create package using evaluated version number.

The last step was done by the PowerShell command:

```
nuget pack path/tofile.nuspec -Version (get-item env:GitVersion_InformationalVersion).Value
```

As you can see the version is taken from environment variable defined by GitVersion. 
Now I want to migrate the build to a FAKE build script.

I have these dependencies defined in my script.

```
"Clean"
  =?> ("GitVersion", Choco.IsAvailable)
  ==> "RestorePackages"
  ==> "BuildApp"
  ==> "CreatePackage"
  ==> "Default"
```

Git version step is straightforward.

```
Target "GitVersion" (fun _ ->
    "gitversion.portable" |> Choco.Install id
    Shell.Exec("gitversion","/l console /output buildserver" ) |> ignore
)
```

I can see in my logs that variables are set by GitVersion.

> Adding Environment Variable. name='GitVersion_SemVer'
>   value='1.1.1-xxx'

The next step is to create the package.

```
Target "CreatePackage" (fun _ ->
    TraceEnvironmentVariables()
    let version = 
        match buildServer with 
        | AppVeyor -> environVar "GitVersion_SemVer"
        | _ ->  baseVersion + "-local"
    NuGet (fun p -> 
        {p with
            OutputPath = packagingDir
            WorkingDir = "."
            Version = version
            Publish = false }) 
            nuspecFileName
)
```

I'm printing all the variables defined, after that I'm trying to get the version by reading variable and assigning it to `version`.

Unfortunately `version` stays empty when I run the build. After I added `TraceEnvironmentVariables()` method call I can see that none of the variables defined by GitVersion is presented in the output.

As John Palmer and dustinmoris said the process started by `Shell.Execute` sets all variables as process-level ones.

Is there a way to use `Shell.Execute` so that the process can set global scope environment variables?

**UPD**

As a workaround, I've added extra step in `AppVeyor.yml` config file:

```
init:
  - git config --global core.autocrlf input
install: 
  - choco install gitversion.portable -y
before_build:
  - ps: gitversion /l console /output buildserver /b (get-item env:APPVEYOR_REPO_BRANCH).Value 

build_script:
  - cmd: build.bat BuildApp
```

In this case, variables are set in a global scope and I can get them and use in my build script.

Obviously, PowerShell starts GitVersion in a different way. I guess, I should mimic it somehow in my build script.

So my question remains the same, how to use GitVersion as a target in my script and get the version number back.

Comment: The basic problem is that when you run the script it looks like it has a different set of environment variables.  You probably need to inspect the shell.exec call and see if you can access the environment variables there

Comment: hm, that makes sense, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at Fake GitVersionHelper? http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-gitversionhelper.html

```
#r "packages/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll"
open Fake
open Fake.GitVersionHelper

let version = GitVersion (id)

printfn "FullSemVer %s" version.FullSemVer
printfn "NuGetVersionV2 %s" version.NuGetVersionV2
```

Comment: Thank you, for this update. This helper was implemented few month after I raised this question.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you create a process-level environment variable. After you exist the shell process the next step which runs in a different process doesn't know about any env vars which you set there.

You will have to set a permanent environment variable like user-level or machine-level one.

Have a look at the [Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes(v=vs.110).aspx) method in .NET.

Example:

`Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("key", "value", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);`

However, I don't think this is a good solution though. I don't know GitVersion and frankly don't understand why you need this thing. Can your build script not determine the semantic version itself? Clearly setting the sem version is a manual step, because no automation tool would know how to correctly increment the version based on your code changes. So you should pick one place in your project (1 file, like readme notes, or anything else where it makes sense) to set your semantic version and have all other tools read it from there to set assembly versions during the build, package nuget packages, create tags in git, etc..

Comment: Thank you for your input. GitVersion is a tool to automate some of the actions you listed. Stable versions are tagged manually, the rest is config and convention driven. Anyway, I'd like to avoid reimplementing this tool in my script, and that's why setting variables myself is not a suitable solution for me.

Comment: Okay, maybe I misunderstood your question then. It sounded like you already "reimplement" the appveyor.yml by building your own custom FAKE driven build script.

Comment: I don't want to rebuild GitVersion. But I do want to keep AppVeyor config short. That's why I'm moving everything to FAKE script.